# Is there a reason pg_shadow shows a password, yet log shows no password assigned?

Tags: postgresql, authentication, sqlalchemy, passwords

I created a new postgresql 11 database cluster. I wrote a simple CRUD script using SQLAlchemy to test the connection on localhost and get "user authentication failed" output from python.

I checked the `pg_hba.conf` file for the new cluster and it shows:

```
local   all             ian                        peer
```

Already checked `pg_authid` and `pg_shadow` which clearly shows md5 password assigned to the db owner "ian." Also, I have checked that the new cluster is running with pg_lsclusters and it shows it running on port 5433. Checked logs after connection attempts and get the following message:

```
2018-11-16 10:00:59.712 PST [2102] ian@iandb1 DETAIL:  User "ian" has no password assigned.
    Connection matched pg_hba.conf line 94: "host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5"
```

A little background: I have already connected this script to the default DB cluster owned by postgres. I can connect and perform the CRUD operations fine with the postgres username and password in the connection string.

Any help would be appreciated. I think there is some type of change I need to make, but can't imagine where it needs to happen. Still learning the ropes.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I hope this post saves someone else a little frustration, immediately after submitting this question-- which had me stumped for several hours, I found this:

source: [link to article](https://blog.2ndquadrant.com/how-to-safely-change-the-postgres-user-password-via-psql/)

> By default, when you create a PostgreSQL cluster, password authentication for the database superuser (“postgres”) is disabled. The simplest and safest way to add a password to the “postgres” user is to connect to the local server using “psql” (see steps #1 and #2 above), then type the “\password” meta command of psql. You will be asked to enter a password and confirm it.

```
postgres=# \password    
Enter new password:    
Enter it again:    
postgres=#
```

I substituted my new cluster owner name 'ian' and assigned a password. I ran the script and everything seems to be working fine now. These are the little things new programmers have to struggle through I guess... Thanks to anyone who can add to my explanation here.